# Using boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::cancel() and socket::close()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

If I use close and not cancel, there are some problems.

The `close` function can close the socket, and any outstanding asynchronous operations is stopped by returning `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

Why should I use `cancel` instead of `close`?

I worry if some asynchronous operations is executing, the `cancel` could not cancel it, yes?

Like `asio::ip::tcp::resolve::cancel`, I try many times to cancel the `resolve_handler` after calling `async_resolve`, but `resolve_handler` always returns with no `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

I think `resolve_handler` is being executed?

Yes?

Answer (score 7):

Cancel is useful if you want to stop pending operations without closing down the socket.

Note that the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html) recommends using close for greater portability (from doc page):

> ...
>   For portable cancellation, consider
>   using one of the following
>   alternatives:
>
> - Disable asio's I/O completion port
>     backend by defining
>     BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP.
> - Use the
>     close() function to simultaneously
>     cancel the outstanding operations and
>     close the socket.

Comment: Note however the remarks for cancel() also state *When running on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and later, the CancelIoEx function is always used. This function does not have the problems described above.*

Comment: thank you and Sam Miller for help,i understand a little now,thank you

Answer (score 7):

`cancel` won't close the socket, so use `cancel` if you intend to continue using the socket object.  In particular, if you have code in asynchronous handler methods that references the socket's member functions, you may not want to close the socket until you are guaranteed that your currently executing asynchronous handlers have completed.

`cancel` doesn't guarantee anything about currently executing asynchronous handlers, it only guarantees (per the boost documentation) that "This function causes all outstanding asynchronous connect, send and receive operations to finish immediately" in the case of the `socket::cancel()` call, or "This function forces the completion of any pending asynchronous operations on the host resolver" in the case of the `resolver::cancel()` call.  This "completion" means that boost will call your asynchronous handler method, it has no jurisdiction to inject any cancellation logic into your asynchronous handler (not to mention it doesn't know about the handler's implementation to begin with).

I would suggest adding your own logic into your asynchronous handler method to handle the case where the socket/resolver/etc. is canceled.  If you are calling the cancel method, then you likely have the ability to communicate this cancellation to the asynchronous handler method.

Comment: holtavolt is correct, using close() is more portable, but it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your help,yes,i create serveral objects to process http request and put these objects into a std::deque,one task coming,pop_front one object from deque to work,when finish push_back the object to deque,when something error during the connection,send or read,i will close the socket,but in connect and read,i set a 20s timeout,when connect timeout,i want to cancel the callback func handle_connect,in this handle_connect_timeout or handle_read_timeout,i am not sure which one to use,cancel or close,but now ,i think the best one for me is close